# Windows 7 VPN Error 619

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

So I am running Windows 7 Enterprise. This morning I was able to VPN using the built in VPN (Connect to Work Network etc). I had to change my network's IP address range and now the VPN will not work. It just stalls on the Verifying user name and password... message. But then it returns the 619 error.

Anybody know why changing my machine's IP address would cause this problem? Where should I be looking to try and fix this issue?

I have tried this on a Windows XP machine that also had the IP address range change and this still connects fine using exactly the same connection details.

**EDIT**

The internal network range changed from 192.x.x.x to 10.x.x.x. This was done on the entire Active Directory. All machines are running fine and the Windows XP machine, that works going to the same client VPN mentioned above is on the same network. Both the XP and the Windows 7 machines are using DHCP served by the Domain Controller. The client domain is not performing any IP range checks/restrictions.

The VPN is outside the internal network, connection is being made via the Internet and not passing through any other machine, other than the normal domain machines, ie DNS etc. This is passing through a router and the router has the relevant VPN passthrough options configured. All internal machines are working correctly with other forms of VPN, ie Cisco, Sonic etc (these were tested on other machines, they are not installed on the Vista or Windows 7 machines).

After further testing, this is occurring on all Windows 7 and Vista machines where they can no longer connect to the client VPN, however all XP machines can still connect fine. This has been tested on three Vista, two Windows 7 and five XP machines. All machines are on DHCP and tests have been done with both the firewalls turned on and off, as well as with fixed IPs being used.

Answer (score 4):

Some more information on the exact changes that you did would be welcome. Also about the local network architecture, router etc. Also why you had to change the local address range. This information is best added to your post.

Error 619 means simple "A connection to the remote computer could not be established". Which just means that the computer that was before reachable is now unreachable, assuredly because of the IP changes.

I suggest that you verify that the computer is within the segment range that is served by your router or whatever connection you have. This is most likely the problem. Also try and use DHCP rather than your own IP (if at all possible).

Again, some more info might help in giving an answer that's less vague.

**EDIT**

Some things to try. Under properties of the connection:

1. Go into Security and change the type
   of VPN from Automatic to PPTP
2. Change data encryption to Optional
   and select CHAP & MS-CHAP v2 down
   below for your protocols.
   (If you wish you can also use PAP but your password will be sent unencrypted)
3. Under Networking disable IPv6

**EDIT2**

Some more possibilities:

- In Properties for the VPN, Options
  tab, uncheck "Include windows Logon
  Domain".
- Vista/Win7 do not support the older
  Microsoft CHAP (MS-CHAP) protocol.
  Ensure on your VPN server that
  MS-CHAP v2 is actually available.
- Whatever router you're using for outside access may need
  firmware upgrade.
- Some possibly useful links:
  [An outdated network router may not function correctly when you use it together with new networking features in Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932134/en-us)
  [Windows Vista cannot obtain an IP address from certain routers or from certain non-Microsoft DHCP servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928233)

Comment: Thanks for your reply harrymc.

The internal network range changed from 192.x.x.x to 10.x.x.x. This was done on the entire Active Directory. All machines are running fine and the Windows XP machine, that works going to the same client VPN mentioned above is on the same network. Both the XP and the Win 7 machines are using DHCP served by the Domain Controller. The client domain is not performing any IP range checks/restrictions.

Comment: Is the VPN to outside of your network? Does the Win7 machine otherwise connect well to the rest of the network & Internet? And thru which machine? I assume you would have already verified its network connection parameters and turned off any potentially harmful firewall.

Comment: Yes the VPN is outside of our network. Yes the WIN 7 machine connects fine to everything else. I have tried this with all firewalls turned off as my google research suggested that it might have been a firewall problem. I am also having the same issue with Vista machines that worked fine prior to the IP address change, although I intermittently had issues with Vista on SP1.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Harrymc, thanks for sticking with me on this. I have tried everything you have mentioned in your edit and still no difference unfortunately.

Comment: I've edited-in my last-gasp effort.

Comment: Last gasp is how I feel about it also harrymc. Thanks for your efforts.
The VPN Server I am trying to get to is Windows 2003 server. I think it supports MS-CHAP v2, but the key to this is that prior to the internal IP address change on my network, my Win7 machine could connect to it using the same settings. In fact my Win 7 machine at home can still connect to it so I think it must be linked to firewall, router or similar, but will try your suggestions also.

"include Windows Logon Domain" was already unchecked.

Comment: Can these Vista/W7 machines connect to other VPN servers on other networks?

Comment: It appears so yes. I have tried to replicate the settings of the ones that are working to the one that isn't but no luck.

Comment: Logic says that if the problem is just with one VPN server, then the problem is there and not on your side. Maybe something changed on that server, by coincidence at the same time as your IP range change?

Comment: I agree with the logic, but am sure nothing changed on their end as they were all on holidays at the time. I still keep coming back to the fact that the XP machines are still working fine. I think there must be some sort of mapping or something (shouting out ideas only) like firewall rules etc that is causing this to happen. Thanks again harrymc.

Comment: Did you try turning off TCP/IP auto-tunning? (not available on XP)

Comment: I have tried it both with Auto-Tuning disabled and set to normal, no difference unfortunately. I have also done some further testing with other clients and there are a couple of other VPNs that are no longer working. There also seems to be a common link between the ones that are working and the ones that aren't. The ones that aren't working, previously when connected to them you would lose your internal network functions, ie http etc. The ones that still work, you always had access to the internal network also. Not sure if that makes any difference to the possible solution though.

Comment: Last question for 2009: Did XP before also lose internal network for these VPNs?

Comment: Yes, XP was also blocked from internal network (or external I guess technically, http and others do not work, ie GTalk, Web etc). It still is blocked after the IP Range change.

Comment: Does this ring any bell: http://nimlabs.org/~nim/dirtynat.html ?

Comment: harrymc, not really. The client is definitely on a different range to us, in fact they were one of the reasons we changed from a 192.x.x.x range to a 10.x.x.x one. So if you are thinking that we might be having a range clash, then I don't think so... unless you are thinking of something else.

Comment: My guess would be that you're being blocked by some software or firmware that doesn't like your new address range. But I lack  information for any non-vague analysis. I would examine any router or software that sees this difference in IP, like IPSEC if you use it. Sorry, but this kind of problem can't really be solved at a distance.

Comment: harrymc, thanks for the time you have put in, the effort is appreciated.

Comment: I would be very interested in the solution, once you found it. Please add here a comment as alert.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the client or the vpn server is behind a "link balancer".
For those of you who do not know what a link balancer is - It is a device on which multiple links from different ISP's converge to provide a failover and link aggregation solution.

VPN traffic does not like being link balanced. We can find this through a packet capture taken at the client.